# Do I need anther license for MarkLogic Semantic?

Tags: licensing, semantics, marklogic

We have ML 7 (Essential Enterprise - Production) license and wants to use Semantic capabilities of MarkLogic.

As per MarkLogic pricing documentation http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/pricing/ 'Semantic' is in option category. However, we have run couple of Semantic functions like sem:rdf-builder, sem:rdf-parse etc. to check it and these functions are running fine.

Do we still need to update our existing license to use Semantic? Is there any other way to find out our existing license capabilities.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: You can verify the license options very easily by looking at your host status page in the Admin UI. That lists out all options included in your license explicitly. Asking internally to check on legal side of things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MarkLogic doesn't restrict access to features nor are their license keys tied to specific nodes.  It's not possible to tell if you have the license you need within the product, you have to refer your license.

Some MarkLogic licenses include Semantics at no additional charge (Developer Edition, AWS Hourly, some bundles, etc.)

If you are consistent in applying the proper license key to the proper envirorments according to the terms of the licenses, then the host status page can be used to see what options are under that license. But the key isn't the license - the signed license agreement is the license.

The triple index can be present without a Semantics license.  Sparql queries or use of sem: API requires the option.  Performance History, which is not a separately licensed option, uses the triple index.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your friendly MarkLogic support/after-sales person to discuss your specific license requirements or needs. The Semantics stuff is listed as 'option' and broken into about 7 lines. So no one but the vendor can answer your question specifically..

And with that out of the way, My personal thought is that if you have the triple index on, then you are absolutely using Semantics features. Also, your use-case includes using sem:rdf-builder - which creates a MarkLogic specific, triple - which would infer that you are edging on using the semantic features for sure. And lastly, the sem library is namespaced as http://marklogic.com/semantics - more of a hint that its time to call MarkLogic for clarity.

Comment: David I know it is MarkLogic implementation. I am able to read and write triples from MarkLogic server. However, We don't have its Semantic license. So, I just want to know the difference between licensed and non-licensed Semantic.